Floor function for fractions
When using \rfloor and \lfloor function for fractions, we obtain the following unpleasant result
$$\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$$
Is there a way to have the external floor brackets with the same height of the internal fraction?

This is covered in the MathJax Tutorial, in the question itself, under item (5).

Thanks, I’ve serched there but I can’t find it.

Again, it is explained in the linked question (not one of the answers, but the question itself) under the item labeled (5) (which discusses parentheses).

I meant, before I asked the question I couldn’t find it! Now it’s fine. Thanks

You can use \left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor to automatically adjust the parentheses heights:
$$\left\lfloor \frac n2\right\rfloor $$
or you can manually adjust it, with, for example, \Big in displaystyle $$\Big\lfloor \frac n2\Big\rfloor$$:
$$\Big\lfloor \frac n2\Big\rfloor$$
